# Info on Modding Keyboards for Backlight?

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I'm looking for a backlit, ergonomic, wired keyboard (just like [this fellow](https://superuser.com/questions/98616/ergonomic-backlit-and-wired-keyboard)).

I would be very pleased to hear recommendations for existing products but I'm pretty sure that no such things exist (I already tried the Microsoft Entertainment keyboard and it didn't cut it) so my question is: can you recommend any good articles or videos for modding a keyboard for backlighting?

My ideal starting point would be a Microsoft Natural Egoncomic Keyboard 4000 and if you happen to show how I could use parts from a Wireless Entertainment Keyboard 8000, that'd be a bonus! ;)

Comment: @random, @Ivo Flipse, et al: before you close this as 'too localized', please consider Jeff Atwood's assertion that the Stack Exchange sites are all supposed to cater for the long tail:

"•Answers to older questions don't tend to get voted up as aggressively as rapid answers. There's an aspect of the Fastest Gun in the West to our system. Joel and I believe there are two audiences here; the daily users and the long tail. Sometimes a little (or a lot) of patience in order."

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail3958.html

Comment: Off-topic since you first want shopping information, then on the basis that you're looking for help browsing sites. Just ask about modding.

Comment: @random it is borderline but since it's more "does this even *exist* " than "do my shopping for me, monkeys!" I think it's allowable. Title has to go though.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, fair play on the title. I changed it to something that reflects the question I *actually* asked!

Comment: @random I'm not asking for shopping information, I'm stating what I want to achieve as a goal. The fact I included a refernce to the other question is because I think you closed it unfairly. It would have done no harm to leave it open.

Answer (score 3):

[Maltron](http://www.maltron.com/) custom build there keyboards (like the one pictured below) so you can ask for any tailoring when ordering (backlit keys, etc). This is my personal fav in Dvorak.

[image]

Comment: What the hell? Is that a, *keyboard*?

Comment: Yup. May not look great - but the spacing between the shoulders helps immensely. Plus the pure native Dvorak layout is great.

Comment: Wow! That's the craziest keyboard I've ever seen! Something tells me that I ought to try one of these before I buy though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have a hard time with this.  Non back lit keys are made of solid plastic, while back lit keys are made with transparent letters.  You might be able to fit the keys from another keyboard (most likely the same manufacturer). However, not all of them might fit on the keyboard.  I have two Logitech keyboards and the space bars are different sizes.